# HazelcastInstance vs HazelcastClient

Tags: java, server, client, hazelcast, in-memory-data-grid

I am novice in hazelcast and I have a few questions.

As I understand hazelcast comes with two entities `HazelcastInstance`(as I understand it is server) and `HazelcastClient`.
These entities even packed into different jars.

I have noticed that in our project we use only `HazelcastInstance`. I have asked collegues why don't we use `HazelcastClient`. As I understand their explanation `HazelcastInstance` has more possibilities than `HazelcastClient`. Thus

`HazelcastInstance` = `HazelcastClient` + `AnotherFeatures`

But for me it strange that these entities packed to different packages if it is truth.

Please explain me when should I use `HazelcastClient` and when `HazelcastInstance`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HazelcastInstance`, as you said correctly, is a Hazelcast member instance. Therefore it stores information and can execute tasks in the cluster. A `HazelcastClient` though is just a proxy to another running Hazelcast cluster. You can imagine it as the JDBC connector when thinking about relational databases. It neither stores data itself, nor does it execute tasks sent through the ExecutorService feature.

If your colleague name it "more features", well fair enough, I would prefer to say server-server environment and client-server environment :)

Comment: please, explain me when should I choose HazelcastClient instead of HazelcastInstance ?

Comment: We always recommend client-server over embedded clusters (server-server  only). That said, you're most likely to see HazelcastClient in your applications. In the end it depends on your architecture. You probably should read the introduction chapter of the Hazelcast documentation to get a better insight in how Hazelcast works internally and what are benefits of different topology setups.