# Need more insight into Hazelcast Client and the ideal scenario to use it

Tags: hazelcast

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104361/hazelcastinstance-vs-hazelcastclient) on the difference between Hazelcast Instance and Hazelcast client.

And it is mentioned that

**HazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient + AnotherFeatures**

So is it right to say client just reads and writes to the cluster formed without getting involved in the cluster? i.e. client does not store the data?

This is important to know since we can configure JVM memory as per the usage. The instances forming the cluster will be allocated more than the ones that are just connecting as a client.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit more complicated than that. The Hazelcast Lite Member is a full-blown cluster member, without getting partitions assigned. That said, it doesn't store any data but otherwise behaves like a normal member.

Clients on the other side are simple proxies that have to forward everything to one cluster member to get any operation done. You can imagine a Hazelcast client to be something like a JDBC client, that has just enough code to connect to the cluster and redirect requests / retrieve responses.